# Update a table in a dialog box when edited in another dialog box

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, updates

I have two dialog boxes in an html page. ONe lists all the links in a datatable. When I click edit on this dialog, another dialog box opens which actually edits the link. My problem is that the datatable that lists all the links is not getting updated. Please help me with this. I have tried everything but in vain.

dialog1.xhtml

```
<p:dialog id="selectLinkDialog" styleClass="fnp-dialog"
            modal="true" 
            appendToBody="false"
            widgetVar="selectLinkDialog">

            <h:form id="selectLinkForm">

                <p:dataTable id="externalLinksTable"
                    value="#{fnpHomeBackingBean.externalLinks}" var="model"
                    widgetVar="fnpHomeExternalLinksTable">



                    <p:column headerText="Actions">
                            <p:commandLink id="external-link-edit-#{index}" 
                              value="Edit" update="editLinkDialog"              
                              oncomplete="PF('editLinkDialog').show(); 
                             return false;">
                             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{model}" 
                               target="#
                                {fnpHomeBackingBean.selectedExternalLink}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column> 
                </p:dataTable>              
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

dialog2.xhtml

```
<p:dialog id="editLinkDialog" header="Edit External Link" modal="true"
            widgetVar="editLinkDialog">
            <h:form id= "editLinkForm">


                <p:commandButton id="saveExternalLinkButton" value="Save" 
                    update=":selectLinkForm:externalLinksTable" 
                    actionListener="#{fnpHomeBackingBean.saveExternalLink()}">
                </p:commandButton>
                </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: are you 100% sure you reference the other datatable correctly via the `update=":editExternalLinksForm:fnpHomeExternalLinksTable"` ?

Comment: yes. is there something wrong? hv spent way too much time on this one...pl help

Comment: I cannot know since this is code snippets and only **you** can know if there is another namingcontainer. And the update the other way around `update="editExternalLinkDialog"` is also weird since it effectively IS in another namingcontainer, so I'd expect you do need to reference it absolutely via a `:` in front of it.

Comment: basically the rest of the code is structured as follows:<ui:composition template="views/templates/commonLayout.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">

   <h1>Welcome </h1>

   <p:tabView id="tabView"......../> <dialog id..../> <dialog id=..../>

Comment: When I use :editExternalLinksDialog..I get the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: editExternalLinksDialog

Comment: That is very weird, cannot explain that error. Please edit your question and create a [mcve].. And btw, using almost identical id's (just one 's' difference) is error prone (at least also for us reading). Using something like  'selectLinkDialog' and 'editLinkDialog' is more explicit

Comment: Actually, when I put in a backing bean method in update, I see that my update is called before my actionListener.

Comment: [mcve] please... I'm not going to speculate... sorry

Comment: Is this good? please let me know if you need me to do any more changes...just dont want to miss any important part of the code because I dont know what might be causing the issue

Comment: Not really, also read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. Remove the template, remove the tabview, create a minimal bean etc...

Comment: @priya, is dialog2.xhtml included inside the datatable by any chance?

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov...no it is not included inside the datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try with a jquery selector to update your form

```
...

<p:commandButton id="saveExternalLinkButton" value="Save" 
    update="@(form[id*='selectLinkForm'])"
    actionListener="#{fnpHomeBackingBean.saveExternalLink()}">
</p:commandButton>

...
```

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't work. Actually, when I put in a backing bean method in update, I see that my update is called before my actionListener.

Comment: @priya, that doesn't matter, you just misunderstand how update works.